# Existence of the supremum in vector space complexification

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-lattices

I am struggling with understanding the existence of the supremum.

$L$ is a relatively uniformly complete Riesz space. $L+iL=\{φ:φ=f+ig, f,g∈L\}$ is a complexification of $L$.
Modulus in the vector space complexification is $|φ|=|f+ig|=\sup\{f\times cos(θ)+g\times sin(θ), 0≤θ≤2π\}.$
Show that supremum on the right hand side exists.

Put
$h(θ)=|fcos(θ)+gsin(θ)|\ 0≤θ≤2π$ and  $e=|f|+|g|$

$h_n=\sup\{h(2π.k.2^{-n});k=0,1,...2^n\} n=0,1,2...  $

Using that for all $f_1,...,f_n,g_1,...,g_n$ in L

we have
$|sup(f_1,...,f_n)-sup(g_1,...,g_n)|≤sup(|f_1-g_1|,...,sup|f_n-g_n|) $

which is a sharper version of Birkhoff inequality.
It is not hard to see that $h_n$
is an increasing $e$- uniform Cauchy sequence.

I couldn't understand that $h_n$ is an increasing $e$-uniform Cauchy sequence.

[Proof's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmgge.jpg)

Comment: If you consider the sets defined in $h_n$ and $h_{n+1}$, call them $H_n$ and $H_{n+1}$, can you see how $H_n \subset H_{n+1}$?

Comment: Thank you. What about e-uniform Cauchy sequence? And how can I use Birkhoff inequality?